# jQuery Datatable preInit event not firing

Tags: javascript, datatables

I would like to access the dropdown list for length display of the jQuery Datatable before the data is loaded in the table, i have a problem that whenever the user select the lenght of records to display in the table , the table resize and trigger window.resize() and i want to access the dropdown list after the table initialization but **before** the data is loaded, here is what i trying to do but it doesn't work.

```
let table = $('#data-table').DataTable();
$(document).on('preInit.dt', function (e, settings)
{
    $('select[name=data-table_length]').click(function ()
    {
        console.log('dropdown selected');
        window_resize = false;
    });
});

  table = $('#data-table').DataTable({
                        destroy: true,
                        serverSide: false,
                        autoWidth: false,
                        paging: true,
                        order: [[1, 'asc']],
                        searching: true,
                        stateSave: true,
                        scrollX: true,
                        lengthMenu: [[5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]],
                        ajax: {
                            url: '/Observer/GetActiveClientsByProfileId',
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: {
                                ProfileId: profileId
                            },
                            dataSrc: ''
                        },
                        columns: [
                            {
                                title: 'Zone',
                                data: 'LastKnownZone',
                            },
                            {
                        ]
                   });
```

Comment: Just wanted to confirm whether you are registering `preInit.dt` event inside `$(document).ready()` or outside?

Comment: I don't have `$(document).ready()` in my javascript file